# Additional column with figure captions wanted

Tags: captions, two-column

How can I achieve an additional column with index terms and figure captions like [this example](https://www.creative-aktuell.de/de/item-details-indesign-aktuell/item/bilder-fuer-satz-und-layout-vorbereiten.html) made with InDesign? I like the layout and want to make something similar.

Comment: You are looking for `\marginpar{•}`. It is part of LaTeX2e.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches. The primitive ones consist of having a broad margin and using `\marginpar` (included in LaTeX) or `\marginnote` (there is a package marginnote). You could improve marginpar by using the marginfix package.

A little -- not much -- better is the technical approach of tufte latex, there are even some documentclasses.

Well, the disadvantage of all those solutions is that the notes in the margins can not flow over a pagebreak.

As far as I know, the only solution that offers marginnotes flowing over pagebreaks is the KOMA-script package scrlayer-notecolumn, which implements a real margincolumn.

To have the captions in the margin, KOMA-script offers the environment `captionbeside`.